# Tricky problem regarding Bilinear Forms,

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality, inner-products, bilinear-form

Here's another old Linear Algebra comprehensive exam question:

Let A and B be two real $nxn$ matrices.

Part 1)

Show that if A and B are symmetric, then for any $\vec x \in R^n$, $$((A^2 + B^2)\vec x, \vec x) \ge((AB+BA)\vec x, \vec x)$$

Hint: look at $((A−B)^2 \vec x,\vec x)$

Part 2)

Find a counterexample to Part (1) if the assumption of symmetry is dropped.

Part 3)

If $\hat B$ is another real $nxn$ matrix, what can we say about $B-\hat B$, if for all $\vec x \in R^n$, $$(B\vec x,\vec x) = (\hat B\vec x,\vec x)$$

(do not assume that $B$ is symmetric.)

Part 4) Show that for any n×n matrix with real matrices A and B, we can find $\hat B$ so that $(B\vec x,\vec x) = (\hat B\vec x,\vec x)$ for all $\vec x \in R^n$ and $((A^2 + \hat B^2)\vec x, \vec x) \ge((A\hat B+ \hat BA)\vec x, \vec x)$  for any $x∈R^n$.

My work:

I have solved Parts 1 and 2 but am stuck on Parts 3 and 4.

(although, for Part 1, I have something slightly different: $((A^2 + B^2)\vec x, \vec x) \ge((AB+(BA)^t)\vec x, \vec x)$...I am almost certain it is $(BA)^t$...I tried Part (1) probably 10 times, just to be sure, and I still ended up with a $(BA)^t$ instead of the $(BA)$.

For Part 3, I had thought that the equation implies that $B\vec x = \hat Bx, $ so that $B\vec x -\hat Bx =0 $ and$(B-\hat B)\vec x =0 $, which implies that $(B-\hat B)$ is the zero matrix.  Apparently not.  The final answer gives that $(B-\hat B)$  is actually *skew-symmetric*.  How can I derive 
this?

Any help with Parts 3 and 4 are welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 3:** Define $\tilde{B}:=B-\hat{B}$. Then
$$0=x^T\tilde{B}x=\frac{1}{2}x^T(\tilde{B}+\tilde{B}^T)x\qquad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
Since the matrix $ \tilde{B}+\tilde{B}^T$ is symmetric all eigenvalues are real and considering as $x=v_i$ the corresponding eigenvectors we obtain $\lambda_i(\tilde{B}+\tilde{B}^T)\|v_i\|^2=0$ that yields $\tilde{B}+\tilde{B}^T=0$ (all eigenvalues zero and every real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable) i.e. $\tilde{B}^T=-\tilde{B}$ (skew-symmetry property).

Comment: Hi @CTNT, why do you start with $0$ on the L.H.S. of your first equation?  Are you agreeing with me that $B-\hat B$ is indeed the zero matrix?  Also, how did you derive your second equation?  I don't see where you got the norm-squared of $v_i$.  And assuming that this equation is valid, then I still don't think that we can claim that $\tilde B + \tilde B^T = 0$. The eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ can all be zero.  There are no restrictions on the eigenvalues other than that they are real.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: @User001 I will try to answer you questions.No $B-\hat{B}$ is not necessarily zero. Since $(B,x,x)=(\hat{B}x,x)$ we have $x^TBx=x^T\hat{B}x$ or equivalently $x^T\tilde{B}x=0$.

Comment: Ok thanks @CTNT, it's not clear why $x^t\tilde Bx$ =0 for all $x$.  From this it looks like you are implying that $\tilde B$ is the zero matrix...

Comment: @User001 Sorry, I accidentally posted my comment before it was finished. $x^TBx=x^T\hat{B}x$ yields $x^TBx-x^T\hat{B}x=0$ that results in $x^T(B-\hat{B})x=0$ i.e. $x^T\tilde{B}x=0$. For the second equation it holds true that $$x^T\tilde{B}x=(x^T\tilde{B}x)^T=x^T\tilde{B}^Tx$$ so we split the term in two parts in order to create a symmetric matrix i.e. $$x^T\tilde{B}x=\frac{1}{2}x^T\tilde{B}x+\frac{1}{2}x^T\tilde{B}^Tx=\frac{1}{2}x^T(\tilde{B}+\tilde{B}^T)x$$

Comment: @User001 ...Since $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $\tilde{B}+\tilde{B}^T$ then $$(\tilde{B}+\tilde{B}^T)v_i=\lambda_iv_i$$ Multiply this from the left with $v_i^T$ we obtain $$v_i^T(\tilde{B}+\tilde{B}^T)v_i=\lambda_iv_i^Tv_i=\lambda_i\|v_i\|^2$$ The left side of the equation must be zero from the assumed property with $x=v_i$. Note that a real symmetric matrix has real eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Hi @CTNT, I think that you are again claiming, in your second-to-last comment that $\tilde B$ is the zero matrix.  But we are trying to show that it is skew-symmetric...

Comment: And for the part where you say "it holds true that..." ...is not true, you are assuming that $\tilde B$ is symmetric - you can't do that...

Comment: @User001 No $\tilde{B}$ is not necessarily zero if $\tilde{B}$ is not symmetric. Imagine $\tilde{B}=\left[ \matrix{0 & -1\\1 &0}\right]$. It holds true that $x^T\tilde{B}x=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @User001 Also, for the 'it holds true that' part $\tilde{B}$ is not symmetric but $x^T\tilde{B}x$ is as it is a scalar!

Comment: @User001 One last comment. In order to prove that $\tilde{B}+\tilde{B}^T=0$ from the fact that all the eigenvalues of this matrix are zero we need to show that the matrix is diagonalizable. But every real symmetric matrix is  diagonalizable since every real symmetric matrix is normal and we know from the spectral theorem that every normal matrix is  diagonalizable.

Comment: Hi @CTNT, we only know that the eigenvalues are real, not zero, right?  And btw, very nice counterexample matrix to show that $\tilde B$ is not necessarily the zero matrix...

Comment: @User001 No. We prove that all eigenvalues are zero since $$\lambda_i\|v_i\|^2=v_i^T(\tilde{B}+\tilde{B}^T)v_i=0$$